# Testing django with mongodb (mongoengine) and redis

Tags: python, django, mongodb, testing, redis

Be default, django only provides support for testing relational databases. I have project which uses
mongodb (with mongoengine) as primary database, along with persistent redis for other database needs.
I know the way to go is to overwrite TestCase class already provided by django, for different database systems.

But is there any library for django already written for this purpose, so that I don't need to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a python package called [Django Test Addons](https://pythonhosted.org/django-test-addons/) which does exactly what you are asking for. It provides support for testing mongodb, redis along with few other databases like neo4j with django.

```
pip install django-test-addons
```

Documentation:- [Read the docs](http://django-test-addons.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Github url:- [Source code](https://github.com/hspandher/django-test-addons)

Comment: Would this work with django 1.6

Comment: According to documentation it does

Comment: Thanks a lot, perfect solution for use case.